# Flaky "dotnet restore" fails randomly in Azure Pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, nuget-package, nuget-package-restore, azure-artifacts

We use Azure pipelines to build a .NET6 project. Recently, we switched build agents (and organisation) for our pipelines. We've seemingly adjusted for this, but our pipelines fail about 20-70% (seems to vary a lot) of the time on the `dotnet restore` step:

```
      - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    displayName: "dotnet restore"
    inputs:
      command: "restore"
      projects: "**/Company.Project.sln"
```

The errors we get are of this kind:

```
The plugin credential provider could not acquire credentials. Authentication may require manual action. Consider re-running the command with --interactive for `dotnet`, /p:NuGetInteractive="true" for MSBuild or removing the -NonInteractive switch for `NuGet`  

error NU1301: Unable to load the service index for source {source outside our new organisation} (many of these)
```

We specify nuget source in `nuget.config`. It links to a feed in Azure Devops (Artifacts). Our feed includes the sources that the errors say are missing. It's always warning about sources outside our organisation.

This is our `nuget.config`

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <packageSources>
    <!-- remove any machine-wide sources with <clear/> -->
    <clear />
    <add key="ProjectName" value="https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/organisationname/ProjectName/_packaging/RepoName/nuget/v3/index.json" />
  </packageSources>
</configuration>
```

Our feed, project and repo have the same name, so nevermind if I messed up the name substitution.

**Things I've tried:**

- add `--interactive` to dotnet restore
- add '--no-cache' to dotnet restore
- add a `NuGetAuthenticate@1` step above dotnet restore
- add a PAT in the nuget config with the packageSourceCredentials tags
- likely more I'm forgetting

Any other tips are greatly appreciated. Been stuck on getting consistent successful builds for some time now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To any sorry soul who stumbles upon this. It finally works consistently after adding these to to the dotnet restore step

```
      feedsToUse: select
      vstsFeed: X/Y
      includeNuGetOrg: false
```